# List applied sequelize migrations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Is there a way to show the migrations already applied ?

I would like to know which migration is the last one, so I can decide whether to undo it or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the helper method as mentioned by @mcranston18. In addition you can also pass an `env` variable as well to select the database you want to query.

```
NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate:status
```

which will give you an output like this

[image]
`Up` means that the migration has run against the current database and down means it hasn't.

The default env would be picked from your `Sequelize/index.js`

This data is maintained by Sequelize in a table called `SequelizeMeta`. You can also query this table directly to know what was the last successful migration.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
npx sequelize db:migrate:status
```

works fine for me (Sequelize 6)

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using the Sequelize CLI

```
sequelize migrate:status
// or if your sequelize is used within node modules folder
./node_modules/.bin/sequelize migrate:status
```

For a list of all CLI commands: https://github.com/sequelize/cli#usage

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers here, you can use:

```
npx sequelize-cli db:migrate:status
```